# Most expensive bug/defect you've seen

Tags: language-agnostic

What is the most expensive software bug / defect you've seen in practice.

There are some famous cases like the [Therac 25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25), but I'm interested to know what issues you've seen yourself or heard of directly. We all have "a friend who used to work at an old company" and would never admit to accidently charging peoples credit cards ourselves.

What problem was caused and why was it caused?

Comment: Are these "Most (hilarious|expensive|whatever) [thing] you've seen" questions really necessary?

Comment: I want to draw on people experience and see what mistakes you can learn from in a practical way.

Comment: Then make it community wiki if it is not about the rep.

Comment: I think its important to point out that bugs which cause people to die - like the Therac 25 bug listed above - are infinitely more serious than bugs which cause only a financial loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can share a story:

Long long time ago, I worked for a company that got a contract on maintaining an application that was basically written in Oracle SP's. I had to migrate one of those, and it turns out that I didn't understand the business, so I migrated it *as is*.

The problem was that the SP didn't do a commit at the end, but returned some data, and the  migrated Java code was exactly the same. What the sp did was to write some data to a table, return a document that contained some billing information, but the billing information was never wrote to the database.

What happened next was that we received alot of payments but didn't know how to correlate them with the database data, so we had to do alot of magick to try and associate the payments.

Answer (score 6):

I guess [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5_Flight_501) ([more info](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/contract/ariane/page.html)) is probably the most costly single failure (500 million USD).

Comment: Did you work on that project?

Answer (score 2):

The [Y2K bug](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1G1-54035911.html).

Comment: Moral of the story: don't introduce arbitrary limits to facilitate micro-optimizations. Make sure your implementation can grow to handle any remotely reasonable size of values.

Answer (score 2):

I once shut down CNA's entire risk management system because I didn't understand what an index was on a database field. CNA approved no new Insurance policies for about four hours because the system ground to a halt. I don't know what the financial cost was, but my managers had to engage in some serious damage control.

I will never again ignore the difference between a table scan and an index seek.

Comment: +1. Ouch. Was there no UAT staging?

Comment: Nope, no UAT, no real System Test, no staging, Nada. There was just development and live. Now that I look back, it was a pretty scary setup.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly there was once a small software bug that multiplied a certain value by a thousand if a , instead of a . was used. Not that big of a deal unless it is the radiation dosis of a cancer treatment device. People died.

Comment: You see, GUI IS important. It should have waited for all appropriate input, then output display the machine's selection based on input and require a confirm. All of this old terminal style single keystroke crap is just begging to kill someone.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did some survey on the cost of technical debt and found two cases:

1. A bug that costed Knight Capical $440 million in about 30 minutes: http://www.cio.com/article/713628/Software_Testing_Lessons_Learned_From_Knight_Capital_Fiasco
2. A bug that costed Trend Micro $8 million: http://www.pcworld.com/article/121825/article.html

These cases show that it could be very expensive when technical debt is out of control.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Heartbleed is probably still racking up millions. I'm sure there are still a lot of servers that haven't patched it yet.

http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/apr/18/heartbleed-bug-will-cost-millions

http://www.eweek.com/security/heartbleed-ssl-flaws-true-cost-will-take-time-to-tally.html